# Dissmiss completion block doesn't work. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller, completion-block

I have `PhotoBrowser` (it inherits from `UIViewController`) as a `presentedViewController`. I present it from `UITableViewController`. The `PhotoBrowser` presents `actionMainController` (it inherits from `UIAlertController`) when I tapped on button. I want to call another `UIAlertController`, when I select one of the actions in the actionMainController and display the second `UIAlertController` immediately after its dismissed but completion block doesn't work. I want to add that dismiss the `actionMainController` succeeds, it works

```
class PhotoBrowser: SKPhotoBrowser {

    // MARK: - Controllers 

    private var actionMainController = UIAlertController()

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    // MARK: - override var

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - functions

    func editAvatar() {
        debugPrint("removePhoto")

        actionMainController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionMainController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            self.deletePhoto()
        }
        let takePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default) { (action) in

        }
        let choosePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default) { (action) in

        }
        actionMainController.addAction(deleteAction)
        actionMainController.addAction(takePhoto)
        actionMainController.addAction(choosePhoto)

        present(actionMainController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func deletePhoto() {
        actionMainController.dismiss(animated: true) {
            // TODO: it
//            self.showDeleteActionSheet()
        }
        showDeleteActionSheet()
    }

    private func showDeleteActionSheet() {
        let deleteActionController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        deleteActionController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .destructive) { (action) in

        }
        deleteActionController.addAction(deleteAction)

        present(deleteActionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint there, does it get called?

Comment: from which class `deletePhoto` method is being called?

Comment: @Tj3n breakpoint has not called

Comment: @Anish웃 deletePhoto is being called by PhotoBrowser

Comment: is deletePhoto() method defined on PhotoBrowser?

Comment: @Anish웃 Yes, it's. I can put the code of the whole class, so you can more clearly differentiate amongst situation

Comment: @Anish웃 I pasted all class

Comment: @Alexsander Do as this `let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            showDeleteActionSheet()
        }`  No need to dismiss since its an destructive action

Comment: @Anish웃 Yes, I hastened to something. Please issue it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your completion handler is not called since your alert has already been dismissed and you are again trying to dismiss the alert.

```
actionMainController.dismiss(animated: true) {

     self.showDeleteActionSheet()
}
```

Instead you should do some work on the completion handler of Action  as

```
let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .destructive) { (action) in

    self.showDeleteActionSheet() 
 }
```